# Why does my custom Google Search say Loading?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I am using Google Custom Search on a site and it just says loading. It worked when I first set it up but now the search box doesn't show up. It just says loading.

I checked the configuration and tested it in CSE but it doesn't work from the website:

http://southernlivingplants.com/search/

In Firebug/Console I get the following error message:

> Syntax Error: google.load('search', '1', );

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your site: `google.load('search', '1', );`

Syntax error.   Get rid of that trailing commma. Don't know about Firebug, but Chrome inspector shows it immediately.